# Orientation issue on android with Sencha

Tags: android, extjs, orientation

I have an orientation issue on my android with an app I building using Sencha.

Everything working great, But when I rotate my mobile a few times the rendering of the page not working as is should be..

Here are the picture that describe the problem the best:

[image: good]

And this is the Issue I having after rotating the mobile a few times(between landscape and portrait)
[image: bad]

Any one have an idea to fix this issue?

P.S: I'm not sure what can i add more to help you figure it, ask for any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems that sometimes bad compiling of sencha apps cos it..
All I did was to recompile it and it's works!

**P.S: pay attention that you app.js is up to date**